# Inconsistent Table Error when trying to sort data with a Python code

Tags: python

I'm trying to fit data from a set of files to a model, and to obtain the chi-squared and the values of all the fits. Then I want to sort and print to a file the results of these fits. I prepare the coderesults to be introduced in an astropy table

```
    Type = [str(path[-25:-18])]
    slope = [poptl_path[0]]
    origin = [poptl_path[1]]
    exp = [popte_path[0]]
    meanlife = [popte_path[1]]
    table = Table({'Type': Type, 'Slope': slope, 'Origin': origin, 'Coef  
    exp':exp, 'Meanlife': meanlife})
    ascii.write(table, sys.stdout, delimiter=' ')
    table.write(f, format='ascii.basic', delimiter=' ')
```

But I obtain the following error message.

```
InconsistentTableError: Number of header columns (4) inconsistent with data columns (1) at data line 1
Header values: ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
Data values: ['<html><head>']
```

Comment: What code have you used?  Unless your problem is reproduceable it is unlikely there will be any answers

Comment: Hi, Simon. A python code.

Comment: Please provide a piece of code (short, preferably) for the people to be able to reproduce your problem. And full traceback, too

Comment: I'm not being critical or anything but an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will assist us greatly in helping you.

Comment: Ahh. I hate it when SO doesn't show me already posted comments on time. Sorry, offtopic

Comment: Hi, guys! Sorry. I had a little problem with my editor this evening. So here you are the code (see above), and the problems I get when running it.

Comment: I have problems when trying to printing only the fit parameters